# How to get URI with Phantomjs

Tags: c#, wpf, phantomjs

I need to get a list of all web-pages in web-site (all links). I have to use Phantomjs, but I never have used it before. Can anybody explain me, how I can use it? How to parse the html code with help of Phantomjs to get all links?

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It's redistrributed as a single executable.

- **Download [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) from the official web site**

There are official release for Windows, Mac ou Linux but you can also build your own version if you want.

- **Create a script**

PhantomJS does nothing by itself, it's just an executable. You have to code/script your action. It's done by javascript or Coffee Script.

- **Run the script**

From the command prompt type, you just have to write

```
> phantomjs yourscript.js
```

Sometimes, your have to create a wrapper for phantomjs. Especially in WPF, use `Process`/`ProcessStartInfo` class to manage the script execution.

- **How to write a script ?**

If your familiar with Javascript and especially Node.js developpment, the learning curve is small. The [quick start](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html) could be precious, and do not hesitate to practice yourself with [available examples](http://phantomjs.org/examples/). That's the most difficult part, but after a few scripts it will be easier.

To answer your initial question, here is a possible script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

if (system.args.length != 2) {
    console.log('Usage: so20189669.js <URL> ');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    var url = system.args[1]; 
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            var links = page.evaluate(function () {
                return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function (link) { return link.getAttribute('href') });
            });

            console.log(JSON.stringify(links));
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
}
```

In the Command Prompt :

```
>phantomjs.exe so20189669.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189669/how-to-get-uri-with-phantomjs
```

There is no magic answer and you will have to alter it depending on your needs !